# SetSelectionContainer example

Tags: c#, envdte

I looking for a simple example using c# to call the SetSelectionContainer method on the EnvDTE.Window class.

I would like to know what the classes should look like that I should pass to the method.

I have really searched the web now for days and could not even find anything remotely helpful.

```
Window window = _applicationObject.ItemOperations.NewFile(@"General\XML File", "", "");
TextSelection selection = (TextSelection) window.Document.Selection;
selection.SelectAll();
selection.Insert("<xml>some xml<xml>", (int)vsInsertFlags.vsInsertFlagsContainNewText);

object[] container = new[] {"Test1", "Test2"};
window.SetSelectionContainer(ref container);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Sets the objects that should be passed to the Properties window
> whenever the window has focus. **SetSelectionContainer works only on
> windows created with the [CreateToolWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.windows.createtoolwindow%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method**. Other tool windows,
> such as Solution Explorer and Task List, already have code for setting
> what is displayed in the Properties window.
>
> SetSelectionContainer
> allows you to associate objects with the window so that whenever the
> window has focus, the Properties window displays properties for those
> objects. For example, you would use this property if you have a custom
> tool window that displays a chart and you want to display properties
> in the Properties window in order to change characteristics of the
> chart.
>
> If SetSelectionContainer is passed an empty Variant value, it
> removes the displayed object. The object displays when the tool window
> is active and the objects are available from the selection container.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.window.setselectioncontainer(v=VS.100).aspx).

Have you downloaded the samples from here?: [Automation and Extensibility for Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc52cke4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I am actually looking for an example, something concreate. Providing a high level description does not really help. I had a look at the examples but only the c++ example had a SetSelectionContainer. I am looking for a c# example please.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have discovered, you can pass simple properties, such as strings and ints in the object array parameters for this method.

It appears that the real trick to making this work is generating the notification (through [ITrackSelection.OnSelectChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.itrackselection.onselectchange.aspx)) that the properties have changed.

There is some working code for this [here](http://www.ureader.com/msg/1545268.aspx).

Comment: I will try when I get to my PC.

Comment: Thanks for the exmple, it does seem that the example is totally related. When I make a call to the SetSelectionContainer method I get the following exception:
Specified array was not of the expected type.